# angular 4 routing issue with child routes

Tags: angular, angular4-router

In my angular 4 application,I have some problem with routing, probably I am wrong something,at the moment the problem is with a routing like this `path: ':code/copy'`, I can route correctly inside to this component but when I am inside it if I reload the page, angular can't load the css files.

in my app.routing I have a path:

```
path: 'ticketBundles',
loadChildren: './ticket-bundles/shared/ticket-bundle.module#TicketBundleModule'`
```

And the structure of ticketBundles is this:

[image: ticketBundles]

So in my ticket-bundle.routing I have:

```
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {TicketBundleListComponent} from '../ticket-bundle-list/ticket-bundle-list.component';
import {TicketBundleNewComponent} from '../ticket-bundle-new/ticket-bundle-new.component';
import {TicketBundleDetailComponent} from '../ticket-bundle-detail/ticket-bundle-detail.component'

export const TicketBundleRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TicketBundleListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'new',
    component: TicketBundleNewComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':code',
    component: TicketBundleDetailComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':code/copy',
    component: TicketBundleNewComponent
  }
];
```

If I make this path as a children `path: ':code/copy'`  how can I route to it? because if I do it it can't match any routes.
To route in some of this component, In the ticket-bundlelist.component I do: `this.router.navigate(['/ticketBundles', code])`

As mentioned before at the moment I have a problem only with this route: `:code/copy` so how can I correct the routing structure to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you should reorder the routes. Angular starts to match a route from the top.

So in this case when you navigate to :code/copy it will look for it in the TicketBundleRoutes starting from the first element. When it finds `:code` it will return with that route and not look further. Move `:code/copy` above the `:code` path and see if it works.

Comment: I have this problem only when I refresh the page `:code/copy`, when I route to the `:code/copy` page it works so probably the order is not the problem

Comment: Is there any error written to the console? Or what can you see under the network tab regarding the css file in the developer tools?

Comment: `GET http://localhost:4200/ticketBundles/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
copy:20 GET http://localhost:4200/ticketBundles/assets/css/material-dashboard.css net::ERR_ABORTED
copy:24 GET http://localhost:4200/ticketBundles/assets/css/demo.css net::ERR_ABORTED`

Comment: How is your folder structure, are the assets under the ticketBundles folder? How are your css files included?

Comment: no, assets is inside src. In the index file I have: `<link href="../assets/css/material-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Are you using CLI? If yes, try adding the stylesheets in the `.angular-cli.json` file under the to the `styles` object. Angular CLI should handle it then.

Answer (score 0):

It was totally my fault, the css path was wrong, I used `../assets` but the correct path is `/assets`
But I don't understand why it's working in all the page with the incorrect path except this, now  with correct path works good